# JBOD SAS adapter for Solaris/Nexenta on Dell PowerEdge 2950?

Tags: raid, solaris, zfs, dell-poweredge, nexenta

Given:

1. One or more available Dell PowerEdge 2950 servers
2. The desire to deploy ZFS iSCSI storage using Nexenta or Solaris
3. ZFS uses software RAID
4. Dell's PERC 5 RAID controllers do not support JBOD
5. Presenting single-disk RAID 0 arrays in lieu of JBOD is not desirable

Question:

1. I would like to replace the PERC with a SAS controller that is supported by Solaris and/or Nexenta.  Do you have any personal recommendations?
2. Would this be compatible with the existing backplane?
3. What about external (MD1000) enclosures?
4. Have you ever actually tried to do this with a Dell server?  Do you have any other thoughts, recommendations, or bits of wisdom from personal experience?

Comment: Does anyone have personal experience running Solaris or Nexenta (non-virtualized) on common Dell hardware?  Good, bad, ugly?

Comment: How many disks of what type are you intending to use?

Comment: Not nailed down.  We probably would start with between six and eight 7200rpm 2TB drives (raidz2) plus SSDs for L2ARC and ZIL.

Comment: I have the same setup and situation, and I am wondering why is it undesirable to present all the disks as single-disk-Raid-0 arrays?

Comment: It's undesirable because ZFS/Nexenta won't be able to rescan the RAID0 array/drive in the event of a failure/replacement. It forces you to have to reboot in order to recognize a new drive. Using multiple RAID0 drives configured through a non-HBA basically kills hot-swap functionality. Use on the controllers listed at: http://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I hadn't thought of that but it makes a lot of sense.  If a drive dies, then the single-disk-Raid0 array will be failed and the only way to fix a failed array is to replace it through the Raid configuration utility in the BIOS.  I haven't been able to install the LSI MegaRaid Utility on Nexentastor, but I supposed if you were able to install it you would be able to create a new array to replace the failed one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, for ZFS LSI non-raid cards are the best.  I use a Dell SAS6i (LSI 1068E rebadge) for internal drives and [LSI SAS3801E](http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/hba/sas_sata_hbas/external/lsisas3801e/index.html) (dual 3gbps 4x miniSAS ports) for external drives (MD1000) under Solaris 10 (s10u9) for ZFS at work, while I use the [LSI SAS 9200-16e](http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/hba/sas_sata_hbas/external/lsisas9200-16e/index.html) (quad 6gbps 4x miniSAS) at home with Nexenta (NCP3).  Nothing but good things to say about LSI cards and support.

Comment: Fantastic.  Just out of curiosity, what model is the server with the SAS/6i?

Comment: I ran my Dell SAS6i/R in a 1950 III (testing) and then in a 2950 III (6mo production) but settled on a Sun x4250 (LSI 1068E too) with its SSD friendly 16x2.5inch backplane since my 1950/2950 have the 3.5inch backplanes.  If you dont have a 8x2.5 backplaned 2950, you can mount SSDs in a free PCI slot (or just hanging out), use a Y-Cable for power from the DVD and attach to one of the internal SATA ports.

Answer (score 3):

We use the LSI 1068 chipset HBA's such as [LSI SAS 3081E-R](http://www.lsi.com/storage_home/products_home/host_bus_adapters/sas_hbas/internal/sas3081e-r/index.html) with OpenSolaris. You can also find that chipset OEM'd by Intel and SuperMicro.

We use these internally on our ASUS boxes w/o a backplane. It should work on a backplane, but we just have that feature.

Answer (score 3):

Dell's SAS 6/ir 'budget raid' adapters do JBOD unless the drive is in a RAID array. The cards work relatively well from my experience although I cannot attest to whether they work with Nexenta or Solaris.

See also [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations/118121#118121)

Comment: +1, looks like this also uses the LSI 1068 chipset *and* is compatible with the 2950 backplane.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there an option to set SCSI mode instead of RAID mode in the PE2950 BIOS? If so, that should do the trick for you.

Comment: So far as I know, this is supported only on old SCSI models (PERC 4) and not SAS models (PERC 5/6), but I will double-check.

Comment: OK. Also, I believe there's an option to disable the SATA and\or SAS controllers, so maybe that's the key. I haven't tried it for myself and presumably these servers are pre-production so monkeying around with the settings shouldn't do any harm.