# Please recommend an 8 port SATA card (No RAID)

Tags: storage, sata

I'm increasing storage on a system and have run out of SATA ports.  Can anyone recommend a 8 port SATA card (No RAID) which supports up to 2TB hard drives.  Thank you.

Comment: why wouldn't you want a RAID controller? If are running software raid and are going to put a card in, you might as well put in a hardware RAID card.

Comment: Would this be ESATA? or is this an internal SATA (HDD mounted inside the PC case)?

Comment: @Zypher, he might be looking to build a cheap ZFS pool, in which case the extra expense of a RAID controller would be wasted. However, the best performance usually comes from good SAS HBAs, the type that typically integrate RAID.

Comment: Closing as off-topic, as [we don't do shopping recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For home use I use IBM BR10i cards
each has 2 sff multiports (8 sas devices per card (4 per port))
3 cards in the file server for 24 disks in the storage array
plus 2 system disks off the on board controllers

IIRC they have an lsi chipset

Answer (score 2):

Port multipliers might be what you're searching for: [serialata.org](http://www.serialata.org/technology/port_multipliers.asp).
And the following link is no ad - just old school tech FYI: [Backblaze](http://blog.backblaze.com/2009/09/01/petabytes-on-a-budget-how-to-build-cheap-cloud-storage/)

Answer (score 1):

See: [ZFS SAS/SATA controller recommendations](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you need but here is the list from a research I did for my recent project:

- LSI SAS 9211-8i
- LSI SAS 9210-8i
- LSI SAS 3081E-R
- LSI SAS 3080X-R
- Adaptec 2805

They all have an entry level RAID controller but is is an inexpensive kind. See if it helps.