# for ZFS: passthru, I-T mode on LSI 9260-8i?

Tags: raid, solaris, zfs, lsi

LSI 9260-8i firmware version 2.0x

the controller menu does only have RAID: 0, 5, & 6

Solaris ZFS requires passthrough or Initiator-target mode to get direct access to disks.....how to get that accomplished?

does it need a firmware upgrade..? any special commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It will not work. You need to use a basic SAS controller. I personally use the [LSI 9211-8i and 9211-4i controllers](http://www.lsi.com/storage_home/products_home/host_bus_adapters/sas_hbas/index.html).

Also see: [ZFS SAS/SATA controller recommendations](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations)

Comment: LSI RAID controllers do not officially support direct access to the target, they only export the disk through a RAID volume. People have tweaked drivers to allow direct access but they're unsupported hacks. The LSI 9211 works fine with recent Solaris releases (mpt_sas).