# Dell H700 Passthrough drive in other server

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc

We have a server that is configured in a Dell R510 using a RAID controller H700. The drives are presented individually to the OS. Each drive is configured as a 1-disk RAID0 array as the H700 doesn't support passthrough.

Is anyone will Dell server experience able to tell me if I were to remove these drives from this server, would another generic server (with no RAID controller) be able to see the partitions/contents of these drives?

Thanks

Comment: If the controller is configured in JBOD then yes, another server will see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this situation won't work for you.

If you built this system as a RAID0 configured through the array controller (*and not a proper HBA or passthrough mode*), then the disk still has array metadata on it. [This is the wrong thing to do](https://serverfault.com/questions/634690/limit-on-number-of-raid-arrays-in-a-hp-p420i/634694#634694), depending on the application use case, as you created RAID0 virtual drives that aren't really portable.

This most-certainly will NOT work in an HBA situation where you're working with something other than a PERC controller.

Comment: The H700 controlled doesn't have passthrough, hence this configuration. As such, given the need for individual drives presented, this was not "the wrong thing", but the only thing available to us, save for hardware modifications.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in terms of ZFS and other situations where you need disk passthrough. They [can break](http://serverfault.com/questions/634690/limit-on-number-of-raid-arrays-in-a-hp-p420i/634694#634694) if you use multiple RAID0 arrays and lose a disk. What is the application being used here?