# HP DL360 G6 SAS-4xSATA splitter

Tags: hp-proliant

I have HP Proliant DL360 G6 server with 1 CPU, it runs Windows Server 2012.

I wanted to connect extra SATA disks, so I've bought SAS-4xSATA splitter cable like this:
[SAS - 4xSATA cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPPmj.jpg). Problem is that after connecting the cable with SATA disks (with external power), Windows Server /machine does not see any of the disks attached to splitter cable.
(I have already connected other SATA disks with PCIe cards)

I don't know if I'm trying to do it right... 

Do I need to configure something elsewhere (to see the extra disks on splitter cable) or do something else?

Comment: Tell what model of RAID controller or motherboard did you connect SAS cable on?

Comment: BIOS says: <br>HP NC382i PCIe DP Multifunction 1GB Adapter Port 1&2<br>HP NC382i PCIe DP Multifunction 1GB Adapter Port 2<br>Intel (R) SATA Controller#1<br> Plus 2pcs of Asmedia 106X Sata in PCIe ports- 2x SATA disks on each

Comment: I should say Embedded HP Smart Array P410i controller for RAID

Comment: I understand that the cable was connected to motherboard. Please, model of it.

Comment: None of this sounds right. What exactly are you trying to do, and why? The HP ProLiant DL360 G6 has up to 8 hot-swap drive bays that should be connected to the on-board Smart Array controller. Why aren't you doing that?

Comment: CPU-Z and wmic shows only "ProLiant DL360 G6". I have only 4-hot-swap drives on 1 SAS cable, I wanted to add more SATA disks on second SAS port ...

Comment: Are these 2.5" (SFF) or 3.5" (LFF) disks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HP RAID 410i controller dosn't support JBOD mode of disks. Create new logical drives from real HDD's in BIOS RAID setup mode when server will boot. Windows will see only logical drives on this controller. You can see same answer at  https://serverfault.com/questions/267751/hadoop-jbod-disk-configuration-on-hp-smart-array-410-i-disk-controller

Comment: Thanks, Works fine! I forgot that I have to create a RAID volume, as you said: no JBOD mode...