# Third-party SSD in Proliant g8?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ssd, sas, hp-smart-array

Anyone having success with third-party SATA or SAS drives with Proliant G8's? I know the G7's were flaky and had BIOS issues.

We're looking for real-world success stories with particular brands and models of enterprise-class SSDs.

(We'd hoped to install some Intel 910 cards, but they're so scarce these days it's impossible to locate them before our implementation deadline.)

Answer (score 5):

G7's were not flaky. Some SSD's did not work, but many did.

What are you trying to achieve? If its a cost issue, you could try to source the OEM SSD's. Last I checked, HP was using Intel for low-end SATA and Sandisk/Pliant for enterprise SAS. Of course, you'll need HP Gen8 drive carriers... I do NOT know where to find those...

But take a look at my notes at: [HP D2700 enclosure and SSDs. Will any SSD work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/380187/hp-d2700-enclosure-and-ssds-will-any-ssd-work/380339#380339)

That covers some of my experiences...

[image]