# Proliant dl380p gen8 Debian booting

Tags: debian, hp-proliant

I created new array in Smart Array controller. 2 disks in Raid-1.

I have installed the latest stable version of Debian 7.8
The installation was successful, but after it does not load with message:

`Attempting to boot from disk C:`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove any USB keys you may have used for the installation. You may have also written the boot loader to the wrong device. The SCSI enumeration changes when you involve USB devices at install-time. Did you write to your Smart Array (e.g. /dev/sdb)?

Also see: [Ubuntu installation can't detect hard drives](https://serverfault.com/questions/658169/ubuntu-installation-cant-detect-hard-drives/658175#658175)

Comment: It helps me a lot: You mentioned that you installed Ubuntu with a USB drive. That would impact the enumeration of the SCSI devices presented during the GRUB installation:

When it comes to installing the grub bootloader, make sure you specify the HD disk device (/dev/sdb) and not the USB stick (/dev/sda) otherwise it won't boot when you remove the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

This message is printed by some existing DOS/Windows bootloader, that is found by BIOS before Debian.

Check boot device order in BIOS and set RAID with Debian bootloader as first boot device.

Comment: Boot device order is ok. I have only 1 array and 1 controller turned on. I tried different BIOS settings, but it doesnt help.

Comment: So it seems that Debian wasn't able to write its bootloader to disk. Apart from the cause, this message comes from Windows XP or later bootloader, so this bootloader is still visible (hasn't been overwritten).

Comment: I think about it. But, what should i do to fix it? I have almost no experience with server problems. I rebuilt raid and formatted disks. I tried again to reinstall. It doesnt help.