# Dell PowerEdge 1950 how use "raw" disk instead hardware raid Perc 5/i

Tags: raid, dell, hardware-raid

I have Dell PowerEdge 1950 with hardware raid Perc 5/i.

I want use software raid md/lvm.

Is any way to totally disable this raid and see "raw" sata disks?

I play alot with BIOS , enable SATA, disable raid controller, but nothing happents, i not see the disks.

Any advice?

Comment: out of curiosity - can you please tell why do you prefer md/lvm instead of perc in this case? thx!

Comment: I hate this perc. Its slow, and low featured. For example i have 2 disk 500G and 1T and want create 500G raid1 and 500G without raid. With perc - i cant do that. Also Megacli utility - terrible. Also md and lvm works very well.

Comment: "Its slow" it is not any slower than software raid will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the LSI controller. I've every single disk exported as a JBOD device.

Comment: Jbod with one disk, look like raid0 on one disk. Thanks. Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use a filesystem solution like [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS), which prefers RAW disks? If so, the better long-term approach is to use a dedicated SAS controller (HBA) instead of a RAID controller. I tend to prefer [LSI's offerings](http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/HBAs.aspx).

Also see: [ZFS SAS/SATA controller recommendations](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations)

Comment: Thanks alot. Yes, i want something like zfs, but on this hardware, without upgrades. Just wonder if it possible.

Comment: Nope. Not unless you create RAID 0 arrays comprised of one disk each and present the resulting volumes to ZFS.