# Install server 2012 on HP ML110 G7 with B110i controller, no disks found

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, windows-server-2012, hp-smart-array, storage-spaces

I'm trying to install Server 2012 on a HP ML110 G7 with a B110i controller and four non hot-swappable SATA drives.

I just can't get the Server 2012 boot disk PE environment to find any disks.

- I have downloaded the latest SPP (Service Pack for Proliant 2012.10)
  and flashed the BIOS.
- I have tried two different HP drivers for B110i and Windows X64, 6.18.0.64 and
  6.18.2.64 to no avail.
- I have tried setting the controller to both AHCI and legacy mode in
  the BIOS, no difference.

HP:s SmartStart disc for G7 servers only support installation of up to Windows Server 2008R2.

HP:s installation instructions for Server 2012 Essentials says boot from the windows disk and use the storage drivers found on the SPP (I can't find any storage drivers on the SPP disk).

Comment: No, I was hoping to avoid using raid in the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a logical drive in the RAID controller's BIOS first. This is called the *"Option ROM Configuration for Arrays"*

`When prompted during the start-up sequence, access ORCA by pressing the F8 key`
 then choose `Create Logical Drive`

From there, you can use the menus to select your drives and desired RAID level.

If you want a graphical utility, you may use the [standalone Array Configuration Utility CD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=12169&prodSeriesId=420469&prodNameId=3670868&swEnvOID=4049&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-018f433e579a4d3e863a1e2653).

This is also covered in the [Smart Array B110i documentation](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01706551/c01706551.pdf).

--edit--

I should add, you can create *FOUR* RAID-0 arrays comprised of ***one*** disk each in the BIOS array configuration utility. Windows will see that as four separate drives, and you should be able to proceed.

Comment: I have to run a raid level? I was hoping to run the disks as regular SATA disks and use storage spaces in Server 2012 to handle the disks directly.

Comment: Not going to happen with that controller. [See this question.](http://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations) You will want a controller that can present RAW disks like an [LSI 9211-8i.](http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/storagecomponents/Pages/LSISAS9211-8i.aspx)

Comment: @Molotch See my edit for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, apparently HP in it's infinite wisdom have limited the number of virtual drives to two. Guess you can buy an upgrade license.

Comment: @Molotch That's a limitation of the B110i controller. It's meant to be low-end. Your best choice for the cost is an [LSI 9211-4i (4-port) SAS controller](http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/storagecomponents/Pages/LSISAS9211-4i.aspx). It'll do the job with no hassles.