# DELL FS12-SC PERC 6/i replacement with JBOD support?

Tags: raid0, dell-perc, perc6, storage, ceph

I have 3 DELL FS12-SC servers with a bunch of 3TB drives (issue number 1, the perc 6/i doesn't appear to support 3TB drives). I'm setting up a ceph cluster and need to run the drives in JBOD mode. The perc 6/i doesn't support that either. The best you can do is a bunch of single drive raid 0 arrays, but that's a pain in the neck if you have to replace a drive. Anyone know of a drop in replacement (these are sata drives) that handles JBOD, 3TB drives, and is reasonably priced (subjective I know)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that is a custom build server. I presume the perc 6/i is on the motherboard.
Assuming you have an appropriate pci-e slot available, I would just add a SATA  controller HBA (one which can operate in IT mode, not a "Raid" one), and connect it to the backplane.

I like LSI controllers and have been using the 9207-8i  - I'm doing SAS (however they can do SATA as well)
You can also look at this: [ZFS SAS/SATA controller recommendations](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations)

Comment: I ended up purchasing 3 LSI LSI00301 (9207-8i) adaptors, and for anyone else that runs into this, I also purchased 3  Mini SAS 36pin (SFF-8087) Male to SAS 32pin (SFF-8484) Female Cables to go from the new LSI card to the backplane in the server.